# mime_content_type issue with some extension

Tags: php, mime-types, file-extension

I try mime_content_type() / finfo_open(). It is ok for .doc but return 'application/zip' for .docx and nothing for .xls

what is the problem ? is it a issue with my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is basically the same: [PHP 5.3.5 fileinfo() MIME Type for MS Office 2007 files - magic.mime updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807036/php-5-3-5-fileinfo-mime-type-for-ms-office-2007-files-magic-mime-updates)

And it seems there is no solution. It's not your browser, it's a mime "magic" file that tried to guess, and there is no way to tell the different between docx and a zipfile because docx IS in fact a zipfile!

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and may or may not be using php>=5.3.0 servers for whatever reason and want to use one set of code for all servers, and perhaps insist on involving the mime_content_type function somehow for servers that do not have Fileinfo, then you can use a half-arsed solution like mine, which is to make a replacement function which is that on php>=5.3.0 it uses Fileinfo, and on lower versions, if the filename ends in a specific string unique to something you want to override, it returns your hardcoded value, and calls mime_content_type() for all other types. However, of course this will NOT work if the file is of a type that mime_content_type() incorrectly detects and where the file name does not end in an extension, but that should be very rare.

Such a solution might look something like this:

```
function _mime_content_type($filename)
{

        //mime_content_type replacement that uses Fileinfo native to php>=5.3.0
    if( phpversion() >= '5.3.0' )
    {

        $result = new finfo();

        if (is_resource($result) === true)
        {
            return $result->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        }

    }

    else
    {

        if( substr( $filename, -5, 5 ) == '.docx' )
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
        else if( substr( $filename, -5, 5 ) == '.xlsx' )
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
        else if( substr( $filename, -5, 5 ) == '.pptx' )
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.presentation';
        //amend this with manual overrides to your heart's desire


        return mime_content_type( $filename );

    }

}
```

and then you simply have to replace all your calls to mime_content_type with calls to _mime_content_type.